# How hot will a carbon electrode get in an electrolysis setup?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, heat, electrolysis, carbon-allotropes

For the electrolysis of sulfuric acid, I plan to use carbon graphite electrodes at voltages up to 6 V. I would like to know if my carbon electrodes would get considerably hot or warm (45 °C or higher).

Answer (score 3):

Supposing there is a powerful DC source, then quite hot, unless small enough electrode current density is managed.

6 V is quite high voltage for electrolysis. But it is possible the source will not be able to provide the current for the voltage 6 V, unless the electrode area is small.

Consider also the graphite electrodes may get deteriorated by the released gas, releasing small carbon particles to the solution (remembering my own first electrolysis experiments with carbon electrodes from old Leclanché batteries, when I was 12).

Comment: Would it be hot enough to melt or damage dialysis tubing ?

Comment: Well, depending on geometry and electric conditions, it can have huge range of temperature, so it cannot be told a priori. You need to experiment what current the tubing can withstand. Generally, the smaller current density in mA/cm2, the better. Plus, the total electric power per solution surface will determine the solution temperature.